# Flutter Extend ThemeData, add colours etc

Tags: flutter, extend, themedata

I am trying to extend the color scheme used by my first app. I created a separate file that contains the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Testy extends CupertinoThemeData {
  final Color bgws = Color.fromRGBO(120, 120, 120, 1);
}
```

I then imported it into Main.Dart but cannot see how to use my new color. I thought `Testy.bgws` would do it but clearly I am missing something.

Comment: `Theme.of(context).cupertinoOverrideTheme`

Answer (score 1):

You can use default `textTheme` without Cupertino
like

```
    final ThemeData appThemeLight = ThemeData(
      /// theme
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    
      /// screen
      primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    
      /// brightness color
      accentColor: Colors.white,
    
      /// opacity color
      hintColor: Colors.grey,
    
      /// here you can add cupertino
      cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.black,
      ),
....
```

and use it `Theme.of(context)...`

also don't forget add `appThemeLight` to `MaterialApp` like `theme: appThemeLight`